# Sampling issue with query in BigQuery (Standard SQL)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been running a query of the format below

```
SELECT b.date as Date,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS NewUsers FROM (
SELECT user_id,MIN(date) as min_date
FROM tableA
WHERE date >= '2018-10-10'
AND filter1 = "XYZ"
GROUP BY ) a
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT date FROM tableB
WHERE date >= '2018-10-19' AND date <= CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1) b
WHERE a.date >= DATE_SUB(b.date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND a.date <= b.date
GROUP BY 1
```

Let's say the above is **result1**

```
SELECT b.date as Date,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS NewUsers FROM (
SELECT user_id,MIN(date) as min_date
FROM tableA
WHERE date >= '2018-07-10'
AND filter1 = "XYZ"
GROUP BY ) a
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT date FROM tableB
WHERE date >= '2018-07-19' AND date <= CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1) b
WHERE a.date >= DATE_SUB(b.date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND a.date <= b.date
GROUP BY 1
```

The above is **result2**

Here **2018-07-19** is the launch date.

Since I have the data till **2018-10-19**, I want to run the query from the later date to optimize the cost and the data consumption by the query....but some how, I am getting incorrect data.

But, if I run the same query from the launch date, I am getting the correct results.

I mean the `NewUsers from result1` for the corresponding dates (like date >= 2018-10-19) are more than the `NewUsers from result2`.

No sure, where I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think - it is because of use of 'MIN(date)' - You see shift in counts because you restricted dates so those users who were first seen in earlier dates - now those same "old" users are counted for recent days - thus the confusion